# What are a few 3d cube (desktop managers) for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, 3d-graphics, desktop-environments

I am using Snow Leopard 10.6 and every desktop manager that I can find and install won't work. What can I try or apps that you know that I can try that will work on 10.6?

Comment: It would help to know what you have already tried.  Desktop manager not working? http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/12682/desktop-manager

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for. Spaces isn't enough? you want something more structured?

Answer (score 1):

I did a google search for "3D cube desktop manager" and I [found this](http://www.thinkinbytes.com/en/products/cubedesktop/), which seems to me to be a Windows desktop manager which tries to emulate the latest Mac OS X features. So what you're looking for is already baked into Mac OS X.

(See [Exposé](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/expose.html) and [Spaces](http://www.apple.com/pro/tips/spaces.html)…)

Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing something. Because this type of thing *isn't* built in.